# Any wordpress development tool to query its functions?

Tags: wordpress, devtools

I'm developing Wordpress advanced sites. I have to do a lot of functionalities programmatically, and I need to call a lot of Wordpress functions to access to database with specific queries, get data of users, sanitizing inputs, etc.
Now I'm debuggin my code getting results in debug files with file_put_contents function or printing it in error_log. But this is very slow and impractical.

I want to have some advice from advanced users about if exists some development tool to access wordpress functions more organized and efficient than I'm doing.

For example.
I want to have array of post with post_type = 'custom_post'
In my code I do an WP_Query with neededs arguments and later I dump it to file with file_put_contents function and read it to show result.

I'm looking for tool to can write the same WP_Query and get the result faster. Like a SQL query in PHPMyadmin, where you make a query and get the result.

Or I want to know which is the result of sanitizing function of string, can call sanitizing_function('my string') and check the result instantly without print it in file or log.

I don't know if some tool do what I´m looking for.

Thank you so much